# Magento 2: Cart product image shows 404 error in new products

Tags: product, magento2.3, cart, product-images, image

I have uploaded some new products to my store, and when I add some of the new product to the cart, the images are not seen:

[image]

And this happens because the image are not generated in pub/media/catalog/product/cache:

[image]

I have tried to deploy, compile, reindex, flush cache but this doesn´t work. I also have tried to catalog:images:resize but it takes a long time:

[image]

The funny thing is that with the old products it doesn't happen, it's with the new ones that I've uploaded...

What can I do?

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with the command **php bin/magento catalog:images:resize** 6h later :)

[image]